# Avaudio player freezes app for 1/2 sec

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation

I get the following message just before playing an audio file: "AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count"

This only happens once and never happens again. Anyone knows why this would happen. I only have 1 player.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stall happens while the audio source is being loaded.  You can pre-load the audio source with [audio prepareToPlay];